# How to add a photo to android built-in Gallery in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, gallery

In my application I take a photo (in a Fragment) and then I am trying to save it into the Gallery. When I go to the Gallery it is not there. It only stays in the app folder. I was following the android docs. Everything else worked fine.

I have tried this code from the docs but ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE is deprecated. And I was unable to find any alternatives which were not deprecated or below API 25.

```
   private fun galleryAddPic() {
        val mediaScanIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE)
        val f: File = File(myPath)
        val contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f)
        mediaScanIntent.data = contentUri
        requireContext().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent)
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Picture Added to Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

I even tried this but insertImage is also deprecated.

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage
```

Are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perfect way of inserting an image in gallery is as follow :

```
    override suspend fun saveCameraImage(bitmap: Bitmap)
    {
            try {
                val collection = sdk29AndUp {
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
                } ?: MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                val dirDest = File(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES,
                    context.getString(R.string.app_name) 
                )
                val date = System.currentTimeMillis()
                val fileName = "$date.${IMAGE_EXTENSIONS}"


                val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
                    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/$IMAGE_EXTENSIONS")
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED, date)
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED, date)
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, bitmap.byteCount)
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.WIDTH, bitmap.width)
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.HEIGHT, bitmap.height)
                   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                    
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "$dirDest${File.separator}")
                    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
                }
}

                val imageUri = context.contentResolver.insert(collection, contentValues)


                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

                    imageUri?.let { uri ->
                        context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri, "w").use { out ->
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out)
                        }

                        contentValues.clear()
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)}
                        context.contentResolver.update(uri, contentValues, null, null)
                    }
                }



            } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
                
            }
        
    }
```

Comment: This works only with API level 29 and higher no?

Comment: The whole code will work for api 29 and below too , just replace RELATIVE_PATH with DATA and  Remove .ISPENDING rest wil remain the same

Comment: I have updated the code to be used in for all the versions as well

Answer (score 0):

I have played with MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage and it gets the job done. Even if it is depracated. If someone finds a better solution feel free to post it here.

```
private fun galleryAddPic2(imageUri:Uri, title:String) {

    val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(requireContext().getContentResolver(), imageUri)
    val savedImageURL = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
        requireContext().contentResolver,
        bitmap,
        title,
        "Image of $title"
    )
    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Picture Added to Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```